# Error while trying to send email from a aspx page using c# The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.blablabla.foo'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I ahve made a registration page in aspx using c#. I have written this simple code to send mail after registration but it is not working. I know this is vulnerable to SQL injection, but please ignore that i just want to test how a email is being sent.
It is showing error 
The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.blablabla.foo'

Please tell me what is the error and what are the modification i have to make so i can send the email.

```
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(".") + "//uploadimage//" + str);
string path = "../Alumni/uploadimage/" + str.ToString();
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into highly-sql-injection-prone-table...", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

MailMessage msg;
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
string ActivationUrl = string.Empty;
string emailId = string.Empty;
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox5.Text.Trim());
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailId", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox3.Text.Trim());
if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    con.Open();
}
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
msg = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
emailId = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
msg.From = new MailAddress("info@blablabla.foo");
msg.To.Add(emailId);
msg.Subject = "Confirmation E-mail";
msg.Body = "Hi";
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("info@blablabla.foo", "***************");
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.Host = "smtp.blablabla.foo";
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(msg);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", 
    "alert('Confirmation Link to activate your account has been sent to your email address');", true);
con.Close();

Session["New"] = TextBox1.Text;
Response.Redirect("Successfull.aspx");
```

Comment: proxy server isn't enabled may be

Comment: When I am doing an `nslookup` with `type=MX` on stjosephschoolrkl.org I get the MX entry to be `mail.stjosephschoolrkl.org`. Maybe you should check if the `smtp.Host` is set incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates a domain resolution failure, and the error message does not correspond to your code.  Running a quick check using NSLOOKUP, the smtp name does not seem to exist on stjosephschoolrkl.org.  Using type=MX in the NSLOOKUP tool and then asking it about stjosephschoolrkl.org it shows that the mail server's name is just stjosephschoolrkl.org without an SMTP.  I then successfully was able to telnet to stjosephschoolrkl.org on port 587 and successfully typed EHLO and got a standard email server response from the MailEnable email server.

So short answer, remove "smtp." from your smtp.Host line and you should be good to go.